# How to handle nullptr in methods when it is not expected?

Tags: c++, exception

I've a method inside my LinkedList class called `insertAtHead` and it accepts a `Node*` pointer as an argument.

```
void insertAtHead(Node* newNode)
    {
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else {
            newNode->next = head;
            head->prev = newNode;
            head = newNode;
        }
    };
```

`newNode` could be nullptr, how do I gracefully handle the situation in that case?

I had few ideas:

1. Create a custom error class derived from `std::exception` (say `NullPointerParameterException`, and add the following statements before anything in the method.

   `if (newNode == nullptr)
       throw NullPointerParameterException("New Node to be added cannot be a null pointer."`
2. Call `assert`
3. Print a message to the standard output stream and `exit()`

What would be the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Voting to close as POB.  How you handle it is up to you.  You can even do like the standard does and say if you give me garbage then its undefined behavior and anything may happen.  It's all about how much error checking you want to guarantee to the user.

Comment: If you look at the `std::list` you will notice that there the  `insert` function gets the *value* to be stored in the list, and then allocates a proper node itself. Avoids this problem.

Comment: If you expect the value not being null, possibly a reference instead of a pointer is a good alternative... If using pointers, there is not really a silver bullet, it depends on your needs. Imagine your function is an internal member function and you assure from wherever the function is called that the pointer is not null, then assert is a good choice - it will be eliminated in release build (more precisely: if `NDEBUG` is defined), and you do not get any overhead, but when testing in debug mode, the failed assert is a good hint that you did something wrong outside.

Comment: If the function can be called externally, assert is not the way to go any more because you lose this test in final build (unless, of course, you explicitly do not want to check the input in the end version...). Apart from that, error handling is up to your needs - or those of your customer, coming back to @NathanOliver ... (by the way: there is yet another option, returning an appropriate value indicating success or error).

Comment: (3) is definitely wrong - `std::cout` is for normal output; error messages should go to `std::cerr`.

Comment: IMO, If receiving `nullptr` is a bug then use `assert(newNode);` otherwise throw an exception (don't create your own just use `std::runtime_error`). Don't print an error message - do that in your `catch()`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the signature to reference:

```
void insertAtHead(Node& newNode);
```

So caller is responsible to check its pointer.

Comment: A valid pointer is by definition a value that is either a reference to an object or nullptr. If you don't want to allow nullptrs, then make it clear in the method signature that you only accept references to objects, by using a reference.

You can then obtain the address of newNode (when you're putting it into pointers in the body of the method) by simply doing &newNode.